# Getting unsupported_grant_type while trying to get access token from Chrome Rest Client

Tags: oauth2, apexrest

When i try to get access token by calling the below  url from Chrome Rest Client

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
```

by passing all headers

```
grant_type: password
username: username@domain.com
password: *****+SecurityToken
client_id: 3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrAK9L_2UlHYwS_Zi1B_vyAIzVVE4jOdt4i.aJCYuioKS7VsCuokwWAm2uIZKSms
client_secret: 5435274860481357
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In connected app i have given return url as `http://localhost`

But i am getting response as

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}
```

Is there a way to come out of this and call rest services using rest client

Rest Client Snap Shot 
[image]

Comment: can you update this question with your rest client screenshot? what is the client name you are using.

Comment: @Himanshu i have updated my question with rest client screen shot

Comment: you are passing them as header parameter. you will pass them as form data instead of header. please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make change of your request type. Make sure it is POST instead of GET

[image]

**Make sure you are passing parameter as form data instead of Header data**

[image]

Comment: thanks this worked i am sending values in headers now i changed it ...